# Rails app with row locking and transactions on MySQL giving bad data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am running an auction site in production. I have an Auction model and a Bid model. The auction row contains the ending time, current price, number of bids, username of the last bidder, etc. A bid row contains a username, auction id, timestamp, price, etc.

On the auction page, I want to show the auction's stats and the last ten bidders, with the price of the auction at that time. So by saving a bid, I add a row to the bids table, update the user's account, and update the auction row, all in one transaction.

This is my simplified Bid model:

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :auction, :inverse_of => :bids
  belongs_to :account, :inverse_of => :bids
  scope :recent, order('id DESC').limit(10) # used to get last ten bids
  before_create :update_auction
  after_create :update_account

  def update_auction
    auction.lock!
    auction.highest_bidder = username
    auction.price = ...
    # more stuff
    auction.save!
  end

  def update_account
    # do stuff
    account.save!
  end
```

However, when enough people click the bid button at once, the auction stats become inconsistent. The counter is off by one or two, or the highest bidder does not match the last row in the bid table. I thought, since those three writes were wrapped in a transaction, and I lock the one shared row (auctions), the data would be fine, but it's not.

I could rewrite the app to query the bids table dynamically to find each winner, bid count, et cetera but that complicates a lot of other queries I do.

So what is the appropriate concurrency control here? I need to save a winner in the auction row, but I need that winner to be the last row in the bids table. And I'm getting a lot of writes to the same row at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that you open a transaction, here's a way you should try:

```
def update_auction
  Auction.transaction do
    auction.lock!
    auction.highest_bidder = username
    auction.price = ...
    # more stuff
    auction.save!
  end
end
```

Also have a look at [ActiveRecord::Locking::Pessimistic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html)

Another approach is that you don't update the auction when someone places a bid because a bid has no impact on the auction record itself.

Here's how I would do it:

- Assume that every action has an "expiry date" column in the auction table.
- User XY tries to place a bid in the validation process of the bid you do:

  - Check if the auction is still open if not place validation error telling that it's too late to place a bid
  - Check if there's already a bid on the auction that is higher if yes place a validation  error telling that his bid is too low

So this ensures that no invalid bids can be placed. When the auction end is reached it's not possible to place a bid.

To determine the winner you just do something like

```
winning_bid = the_auction.bids.maximum(:amount)
winner      = winning_bid.account
```

Comment: The `auction.lock!` method Violet proposed seems perfectly legit, based on the reference you provided. Is there something wrong with that method?

Comment: Thanks for your response. before_create and after_create callbacks implicitly create a transaction as described here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html. I can also tell by the SQL result all three writes are inside a transaction. And as you can see with auction.lock! I'm already doing pessimistic locking. Finally, I also point out in my post I know how to compute the winner dynamically: I just don't want to do it because it complicates efficiently showing a list of auctions and highest winners and showing all auctions a user has won, etc.